for a website with a live clock, Is it better to shift text or to delay starting the clock?
I run a ticketing website.
On one page I have a live countdown timer (where text inside HTML code changes every second).
If I set my website to execute the countdown instantly, then google lighthouse complains about layout shifts and my CLS score goes up.
If however, I set the countdown timer to begin running 3 seconds after the page is fully loaded then google lighthouse complains that I have many long main task threads.
I don't want to have to resort to making digits of the clock as one image and having that image generated on the server, and javascript loading a new image every second for the next number. That would be alot of numbers and for caching, a lot of storage would be required.
How can I make a live clock without google lighthouse complaining in any way that would work with any web browser?
P.S. I'm not asking for source code

In terms of practice, do you have the whole timer block updated or just the text value (digits)?

What if you try to set a fixed block size via CSS so there is no offset?
Alternatively, you could use requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval or setTimeout to update the timer every second.
